# Why are AI systems almost always feminine?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm curious about this, as to why most of the AI systems found in spaceships and other "advanced" technologies tend to be more female-oriented.

Female-oriented as in, the entirety of the ship/system is controlled by a female AI. Good examples would include Cortana, from the HALO series, Gordon Freeman's HEV suit.  Many movies also do this, where the onboard computer system has a feminine voice.  The only male AI system I know of is HAL (Space Odyssey 2001), and even then, his voice isn't entirely male (more robotic than anything).

IF anything, is this a trend that's been going on for decades? Is this something recent?  Why are most AI systems feminine?

Comment: [citation needed] I don't see any evidence that AI systems are almost always feminine.

Comment: Because the questioner mistakes a few popular mass media products for SF in general.

Comment: @dmckee Now that's no way to make assumptions

Comment: [This question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39133/why-does-the-computer-have-a-human-female-voice) was about *Star Trek*, but some of the answers are generally applicable.

Comment: _Star Trek_ had a unisex voice as well as male voice for computers at times. _Alien: Resurrection_ had a male AI named "Father". _JARVIS_ from the Iron Man movies is male. The Batcomputer has been portrayed as male. Superman's Fortress of Solitude also has a male A.I. in the form of Jor-El. GERTY from _Moon_ was voiced by Kevin Spacey. I.N.T.E.L.L.I.G.E.N.C.E. from _Team America_ was male. Master Control Program from _Tron_ was male, as were Zordon from _Power Rangers_, Eddie from _H2G2_, KITT from _Knight Rider_, and the list goes on...

Comment: "Female-oriented as in, the entirety of the ship/system is controlled by a female AI." - The voice may be female/feminine, but I don't think there's anything particularly gendered about most of these AIs. Does gender even make sense when it comes to a computer?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite *"Does gender even make sense when it comes to a computer?"*  But we're not talking about computers here so much as AIs - a very specific type of computer.  On that subject, researchers in AI have pondered whether it is possible to make an AI that can understand (and thereby intelligently interact with) humans, unless it has a 'human shape' body and has to deal with the types of everyday things a human must do.  Presumably once you go to that extent, the form will be modeled distinctly on 'male' and 'female' forms of existing humans.  Cannot say I am convinced either way on that.

Comment: Now I wonder if Asimov's Multivac had a gender and what its gender was.  The gender of the robots is more clear, thanks to the robot story “Feminine Intuition”.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: well indeed. I’d imagine the more general, and also brain-melting question of “What the jiggins is consciousness, now that we appear to have made it in AI form” would be pondered for a long time before “And does it sound like it has a pee-pee or a hoo-hah?”

Comment: @AndrewThompson There's no need for an AI's physical body to have a gender, unless you were teaching it sexuality.  And human gender is absurdly complex anyway (it is _not_ as simple as male/female), so I don't see why that dichotomy has to be forced onto non-humans...  (Well, I suppose comfort levels of the people interacting with the robots?  [ASIMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASIMO) isn't gendered, though..)

Comment: And don't forget the AIs that have had gender changes, like Bender and Ship from _Futurama_, and Holly from _Red Dwarf_.

Comment: HAL 9000's voice isn't robotic. It's definitely a male human, talking softly and without distortion, and possibly the most "human" voice in the Discovery mission. Part of the genius of the movie is that HAL feels more human than its robotic human companions.

Comment: @b_jonas I don't know about Multivac itself, but in [True Love](http://www.angelfire.com/ultra/savvy/story7.html), one of Asimov's Multivac stories, there's a human programmer who tasks an AI program with finding him the perfect female partner, his "true love". In the end, the program gets rid of the programmer and keeps the female for itself, and self-identifies as "Joe".  I'd say this AI is clearly male.

Comment: Let me ask Siri...

Comment: Don't forget GLaDOS :-)

Comment: Pern's AIVAS was also male-voiced.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't see any all-over gender bias in AI characters generally.
Boats and ships always get the feminine pronoun, that wouldn't change for spaceships. That would bias your AI selection.  Also, various female stereotypes tailored to a primarily male audience come into play, for example, men generally think a female voice is more pleasant. A female AI will not trigger subconscious male-male dominance games. This article from CNN goes into some detail: [*"Why computer voices are mostly female"*](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/10/21/tech/innovation/female-computer-voices/index.html) by Brandon Griggs, October 21, 2011. This should answer the underlying question.

Comment: Some of Brandon Griggs' examples are pretty bad. HAL 9000, for example, which he calls a "homicidal computer": HAL's "maleness" isn't threatening -- instead, its actions are. In fact, HAL's voice is quite friendly and pleasant, purposefully warmer than the voices of the human astronauts. Contrast this to, say, SHODAN from System Shock, a definitely psychotic and scary _female_ computer voice. I would trust HAL 9000 sooner than I'd trust SHODAN ;)

Comment: Or GlaDOS, of course. Homicidal female computers abound.

Answer (score 14):

ImaginaryEvents has some good thoughts. I'd like to add that in Star Trek, the Enterprise computer voice was provided by Majel Barrett-Roddenberry, from TOS until her death. Star Trek has been very defining for the genre, so lots of other fictional computer voices have probably been consciously or unconsciously inspired by her voice acting.

Also, to list a few counter-examples to your premise:

If we look at the *names* on [Wikipedia's list of fictional computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_computers) we see that the majority seem to be genderless, with some male names and some female names. That's only looking at the names though.

Some examples of computers I'm familliar with that seem to be definently "male":

- Eddie the ship computer from the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy
- Marvin the paranoid android, also from the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy
- Jarvis from the Iron Man movies.
- I.N.T.E.L.L.I.G.E.N.C.E from Team America
- KITT from Knight Rider
- As mentioned already, HAL 9000
- Auto the autopilot in Wall-E, but he's sort of an homage to HAL

Comment: ONe of the earliest would be ["A Logic Named Joe"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Logic_Named_Joe) from 1946.

Comment: Mike from RAH's *Moon*

Comment: @DVK, Mike went both ways.  He was also Michelle when talking to Wyoming.

Comment: @cjm For that matter Eddie of the *Heart of Gold* had an alternate, mother-hen personality.

Comment: Interestingly, although Auto (Wall-e) was male, the ship's AI "Muth-r" was female and voiced by Sigourney Weaver.

Comment: When I read the question my immediate thought was, "Because Eddie was so annoying."

Comment: Just want to note Red Dwarf's *Holly* as another popular fiction example of an AI with male and female personas.

Answer (score 5):

I want to say that I read a study done by the US Navy that men react better to a feminine voice during stressful situations, and our auditory senses are more likely to interact with a slightly higher-pitched tone as more suggestive for acknowledgement than that of a more bass-like tone. We see it in movies all the time; the "authorative" figure is some old crusty with a brass voice and an attitude. This is also the same figure that the rebellious type would flaunt against. Now put Angelina's voice in there, and everything's gravy. It's like listening to your mother.

Plus, sex sells.

Answer (score 1):

I find female voices more irritating (as a woman), so I would only have the male version of Siri or some equivalent if I downloaded an AI. David 8 in Prometheus had an incredibly calming voice and I would certainly be happier living with a male AI in the future if I had a choice. But most of the women I know aren't really 'into' technology and wouldn't have much of an opinion either way.

**If men are more involved in technological trends then I suppose it would make sense to see more female AI.**