# Instance of antagonist's computer system being female?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computers

I have noticed after watching several sci-fi movies where there are computer systems involved that more often than not the protagonist's computer has a female voice and the antagonist's computer has a male voice (two instances that come to mind are the Hood's computer in *Thunderbirds* (2004) and The USS Vengeance from ST: Into Darkness - not a comprehensive list I know but they're two that pop into mind).  I was wondering if anyone could cite an instance where the antagonist's computer system has a female voice.  Note, I don't count VIKI from I-Robot, because there is no protagonist computer system as such like in the examples I cited before.  Note, I will accept answers for both movies and/or television series.

Comment: Is this limited to movies?

Comment: @SystemDown - No.  Sorry I meant to clarify that.  It can be expanded to a TV series as well.

Comment: Searching on ["female AI"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=female+AI) yields http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40643/why-are-ai-systems-almost-always-feminine. This may or may not be a duplicate, depending on your take, but I stand by the position that this impression comes from an insufficiently broad intake of SF.

Comment: @dmckee - a similar question granted, but not quite the same as what I'm looking for

Comment: Plankton's computer in Spongebob: http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130408041858/spongebob/images/e/ef/Plankton_Making_A_Chum_For_Karen.png

Comment: Max Headroom and A-7 of Security System

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the eleventh Pokémon movie, [*Giratina and the Sky Warrior*](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M11), the antagonist [Zero](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zero)'s [ship](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Megarig) is controlled by [Infi](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Infi), an AI with a female voice and the appearance of a female maid.

[image: Infi]